# Use Apache Airflow SimpleHTTPOperator with proxy and certificate

Tags: rest, proxy, airflow

I'm trying to use Airflow to get API responses and save them into files for further processing. 
Airflow is in a docker container and it needs the proxy and certificate to be able to connect to the web. When using curl from the docker directly (with proxy and certificate passed to it) it works and displays result, but I can't replicate that with SimpleHTTPOperator in Airflow. 
This is what I've tried;

```
get_poke_stats = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id="get_poke_stats",
    method="GET",
    http_conn_id="http_poke_api",
    endpoint="pokemon/psyduck",
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    xcom_push=True,
    proxies={"https": "http://127.0.0.1:8080", "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"},
    # verify="/path/to/cert/file/file.cert",
    cert="/path/to/cert/file/file.cert",
    dag=dag
)
```

The connection always times out, I've tried both cert and verify and the same thing happens. 
I've tried using different PC with Ubuntu installation. It has access to internet without proxies, and it worked, so it's got to be something with passing proxy and cert variables, but I was unable to find the combination that worked.

This is taken from the log, it looks like the variables are passed through but..

```
Subtask get_poke_stats **kwargs: {'proxies': {'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'}, 'verify': '/path/to/cert/file/file.cert'}
```

And then it just continues to timeout

```
{base_hook.py:84} INFO - Using connection to: id: http_poke_api. Host: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/, Port: None, Schema: None, Login: None, Password: None, extra: {}
{http_hook.py:131} INFO - Sending 'GET' to url: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/psyduck
{local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.03 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.969908 s
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the task run log?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example from the log

Comment: The Subtask log line shows that you are using the `verify` parameter, but the code you posted uses `cert`. Can you also post the error you get from the proxy or maybe just the complete log.

Comment: When I use cert it looks exactly the same as the above approach.. Heartbeat line is repeated several times and then I get Max retries exceeded error.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the Airflow docker via docker-compose as described [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html?highlight=compose), you can add a [Dockerfile](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html) (if not done yet) and add the proxies as build arguments in the first build step. With this the example based [docker-compose.yml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) should start with

```
version: '3.9'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
      HTTP_PROXY: 127.0.0.1:8080
      HTTPS_PROXY: 127.0.0.1:8080
      NO_PROXY: localhost,other_container
  image: airflow:2.1.2
  environment:
     ... as in the example
```

I am using this with requests and it uses HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY for all calls.